# CAS 4.x & Spring Security without SSL

Tags: java, spring, security, ssl, cas

is it possible to use the CAS 4.x Server with Spring Security without SSL?

I already tried to edit the CAS Server settings. 
I added

```
<bean id="ticketGrantingTicketCookieGenerator"
        class="org.jasig.cas.web.support.CookieRetrievingCookieGenerator"
        p:cookieSecure="false" p:cookieMaxAge="-1" p:cookieName="TGC"
        p:cookiePath="/cas" />
```

to the ticketGrantingTicketCookieGenerator.xml

and I also added

```
<bean id="warnCookieGenerator"
        class="org.jasig.cas.web.support.CookieRetrievingCookieGenerator"
        p:cookieSecure="false" p:cookieMaxAge="-1" p:cookieName="CASPRIVACY"
        p:cookiePath="/cas" />
```

to the warnCookieGenerator.xml

I still get the following error from CAS:
*Authentication failed because url was not secure.*

Is there any other configuration which can make CAS without SSL possible or isn't it possible the current version?

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<bean id="proxyAuthenticationHandler"
      class="org.jasig.cas.authentication.handler.support.HttpBasedServiceCredentialsAuthenticationHandler"
      p:httpClient-ref="httpClient" p:requireSecure="false"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

CAS Server were made to be a secure channel to do authentication. So the CAS Server does not work with HTTP. You can change the source of CAS to do it for you, but this does make sense for me.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I hoped I could use  CAS without a SSL certificate... But I don't want to change the sources!